# Need to find out what piano instrumental this is

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental, piano

I keep thinking this is from the 1970s. Most people I talk to know the song, but can't identify the name or where it is from. It is a piano instrumental. The notes are as follows, probably 99% correct for the beginning. This should be enough for someone who knows this song to identify and answer. Thanks. 
Phil

C C (pause) E C E C E G C(high) B A G (pause) G(down ) B G F D B G(down) B D F E C A G

I started 1 octave above middle C, the two Gs down are below the starting point and the one C I put as high is the C above starting point.

Comment: Can you get the rhythms of these notes down, if possible? Music can sound quite different given the same notes but different rhythms. For example, both the 1st movement of Beethoven's 5th Symphony and the main melody of the Imperial March from Star Wars start with the exact same 4 notes, but the 4th note of the Imperial March melody is quite a lot shorter than the 4th note of Beethoven's 5th.

Comment: I have to say, I would never have recognized it from that transcription :D

Answer (score 2):

After looking at other sites, I finally found it.

[Music Box Dancer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qwa0c8VO71s).

Thanks for anyone listening and trying to help.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your answer.